# Is it possible to specify BouncingScrollPhysics for ScrollPhysics in the Flutter DraggableScrollableSheet widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

As far as I have researched, it doesn't seem possible to specify BouncingScrollPhysics for ScrollPhysics in the DraggableScrollableSheet widget. If anyone knows, could you please provide instructions on how to specify BouncingScrollPhysics for ScrollPhysics in the DraggableScrollableSheet widget?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign physics to **DraggableScrollableSheet.**
What you should do is to have a scrollable widget in the builder of the DraggableScrollableSheet and assign the `scroll controller` from the builder to the scrollable. See the below snippet:

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
      initialChildSize: 0.1,
      minChildSize: 0.1,
      maxChildSize: 1,
      expand: false,
      builder: (_, scrollController) => ListView(
        controller: scrollController, //assign the controller here 
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      ),
    );
```

As shown above, i have a listview that uses the scroll controller from the DraggableScrollableSheet and gave it BouncingScrollPhysics().

Comment: Thank you for your response. In that case, I have not chosen that approach because the child widgets do not appear naturally when they exceed the maxChildSize.